# is it possible to use exemption in ucwords and strtolower?

Tags: php

Like for example :

```
$sampe = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA';
$sampc = ucwords(strtolower($sampe));

result : United States Of America
```

I want like this

```
result : United States of America
```

how to exempt "of"?

Comment: You have to do it with some custom methods.

Comment: creating some function. but I did some still doesnt get it.

Comment: If you just want to replace `of` then try str_replace

Comment: I would use `str_replace` to convert it back to lower after `ucwords`

Comment: As @Sougata mentioned: You have to write a custom method. But what is the property to decide if a word needs to be upper case or not? 
A) By Word length
B) By position
C) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$sample = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA';

function convert_str($str)
{
    $except = array('of', 'in', 'is'); // Words you dont want to convert
    $str= strtolower($str); // apply strtolower to all
    return (in_array($str, $except)) ? $str : ucwords($str); // apply ucwords conditionally
}

$temp = explode(' ', $sample); // explode by space
$new_temp = array_map('convert_str', $temp); // apply the function to every element

echo implode(' ', $new_temp); // implode again
```

But it is for the text you provided. It might need to be changed accordingly.

Comment: thanks this what I want to happened. using array. thanks for helping.

Comment: Also, ucwords delimiters are normally `" \t\r\n\f\v"` and not just `" "`. Maybe it doesn't matter in his particular case though.

Comment: Yup @this.lau_.. It is just an example and needs to be changed according to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function

```
    $country = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA';
    function countryToLowerCase( $country )
    {
        $except = array('of','in');
        $parts = explode(' ', $country);
        $country = null;
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if(!in_array( $part, $except))
            {
                    $country .= ucfirst($part) .' ';
                    continue;
            }
            $country .= $part .' ';
        }
        return $country;
    }
    echo countryToLowerCase( strtolower($country));//United States of America
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array of list that you would want to change it back to lowercase, like the following

```
$filterback = array("of", "in", "is");

$str = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA';
$upper = ucwords(strtolower($str));
$filtered = str_ireplace($filterback, $filterback, $upper);
echo $filtered; // United States of America
```

Answer (score -1):

If you save UNITED , STATES, and AMERICA in three different variables and apply the above code individually to these three strings and then save in a single variable. Then you should be able to get the result you want. Otherwise the php is not intelligent enough to see that the country name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: You are posting two answers for a single question. Why not a single answer with proper code example and explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You have to truncat the first variable into three variables. The first variable should contain "United States" , The second variable should contain "of" and the third variable should contain "America" . Apply strtolower function on the first and the third variable . Then add the three variables into one variable to get the required result.

Easy . Isn't it!.